# Linux desktop app development

Tags: linux, user-interface

Recently I made the switch from windows to linux (arch). As a student majoring computer science I have quite some programming experience (mainly java so not really platform dependant). 
Now I want to create some simple desktop applications for my linux machine. For some small projects I made for personal use on windows I used C#.net. Now I want to do something similar in linux. 
I did some research and I guess my main toolkit choices for GUIs are QT and GTK but since I'm using GNOME I'm guessing the best choice is GTK?
What are some good options to get started with?

PS: Something I had in mind for a first little project was a simple download manager, basically a GUI on top of wget since I couldn't really find one that I liked.

(I could use java on linux too but I'd prefer something more "native")

Comment: Qt runs just fine with Gnome. Try out both Qt4 and GTK and see which one works best for you. Both have bindings for a few languages.

Comment: If you're using C, I'd go with GTK, Qt will pretty much force you to use C++, and drags in a lot of dependencies--but it's a solid toolkit. I've made some good desktop apps with Python using PyGTK. Yep, Java's an option too, and recent ones look better.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker There's bindings for Qt for many higher level languages as well. Qt also includes QML in the box, which is a JavaScript-like language, and that can be used to create many simpler apps as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want something fast and easy I'd recommand the use of Qt, since it comes with a [graphical editor](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aTools%3a%3aQtCreator)

C++ is really powerful and you can do a lot of crazy stuff, but you also have to write a lot and scratch your head sometimes. A really good alternative is Python to get things running faster. Qt has binding for Python too, [Pyside](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide) and [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt)

Answer (score 1):

In most modern Linux distributions, it is trivially easy to install and maintain the entire Qt tool chain.  Coming from C#, you are also more likely to find C++ a bit more familiar.

On the other hand, your proposed project might be a bit more instructive should you decide to go the C/GTK route.  After all, `wget` is written in C, and, being Open Source, is [freely available](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/) to incorporate into your projects.  To learn good programming, IMHO, it is more important to expose yourself to code that's stood the test of time *and* is being actively maintained than to fool around with desktop decorations.   Heck, if you discover something interesting, you can drop an email to  [Hrvoje Niksic](http://www.us.xemacs.org/People/hrvoje.niksic/) himself. Now  *there* is a feature that's not available even with the $5,000 Vis Studio Premium.

Also, both Qt and [GTK](http://glade.gnome.org/) have great UI designers, so that really shouldn't influence your choice.   So, really my answer would be, why not try both?

Comment: Good point on the wget written in C, but he could still compile it with g++, and if he's only used to high level OO programming style like java and C#, C might be traumatizing at first sight :P

Comment: @Maresh : he's a CS major, it's gotta happen some time.  Besides, I've been far more traumatized trying to write a simple multi-threaded app in VisBasic.